# Subsetting a Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have some data represented as a dataframe that has some info that changes over time, so for time t1 I have a dataframe df1, time t2 some dataframe df2, etc. Now I have to bind them all together, kinda like putting the tables one on top of another sequentially in time:

I save them as a dictionary with

```
{ti:dfi}
```

Then I concatenate them all as a MultiIndex DataFrame, like this:

```
new_frame = pd.concat(frame_list, axis=0)
```

So I get a frame like this:

```
                                id          metric1     metric2...
2020-01-01 00:00:00 0           someid1     a1          f1      
                    1           someid2     b1          g1
                    2           someid3     c1          h1
                    3           someid4     d1          i1
                    4           someid5     e1          j1
                    ...                
2020-01-01 00:00:01 0           someid1     a2          f2
                    1           someid2     b2          g2
                    2           someid3     c2          h2
                    3           someid4     d2          i2
                    4           someid5     e2          j2
                    ...
```

Now what I want to do is, choosing some id, for example id1, I want to get a new table with it's metrics varying in time

```
someid1:
                            metric1                 metric2                 ...         
2020-01-01 00:00:01         a1                      f1  
2020-01-01 00:00:02         a2                      f2                      ...                     
2020-01-01 00:00:03         a3                      f3                      ...
```

Or even, choosing a metric, then having it's id's values varying in time

```
metric1:
                            someid1                 someid2                 ...         
2020-01-01 00:00:01         a1                      b1  
2020-01-01 00:00:02         a2                      b2                      ...                     
2020-01-01 00:00:03         a3                      b3                      ...
```

I can reason in my head how that would look like with some 3 dimensional matrix, I'd be getting all values along a line in the depth axis, but I'm having a hard time translating that to Pandas commands, if anyone could help, I'd appreciate it, feel free to propose better solutions to the problem also, there may be a better way to do this, just keep in mind that what I have is a lot of tables with some timestamp.

Comment: you can consider creating a dictionary as such: `d = dict(tuple(df[df['id'].isin(['someid1','someid2'])].groupby("id")))` and then use each key for your use

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to select rows from a data frame with a MultiIndex:

First, create some test data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 10
dates = pd.date_range(start='2019-12-26', periods=n, freq='D')
refs = [100 * i for i in range(n)]
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, refs])

data = np.arange(len(midx) * 3).reshape(len(midx), 3)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=midx, columns=['some_id', 'metric1', 'metric2'])
```

Now, show a few examples of indexing.  I'm assuming your data frame is indexed by datetime and ID:

```
# select a range from the outer level of the multi index
df.loc['2020-01-01' : '2020-01-03']

# two ways to select from the inner level of a multi index
df.loc[(slice(None), 100), :]
df.loc[ pd.IndexSlice[:, 100], :]
```

The MultiIndex is powerful, but complex.  Docs here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html